# polynomial $f(x,y)$ with mulitple root at every value $y \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a nonzero polynomial. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is not of the form $f(x,y) = a(x) b(y)$. Then is it possible that: for all $y_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, the univariate polynomial $f(x,y_0)$ has a multiple root?
Is there a way to classify such polynomials?
Any comment or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Just factorize $f$ in irreducibles in $\Bbb{C}(y)[x]$ and consider $Disc(f)\in \Bbb{C}(y)$. If $y_0$ is neither a zero nor a pole of $Disc(f)$ then $f(x,y_0)\in \Bbb{C}[x]$ is separable. So the necessary and sufficient condition is that $Disc(f)=0$ ie. $f = g^2 h  $ in $\Bbb{C}(y)[x]$ with $\deg(g)\ge 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but only if $f$ has a repeated factor. In particular, $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ always has a multiple root, but if $f$ is squarefree, this cannot happen.

If $f$ has no repeated factors, then $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are coprime as polynomials in $\Bbb C(y)[x]$, so their resultant does not identically vanish. Therefore the discriminant of $f$ with respect to $x$ is a nonzero polynomial in $y$ and can only vanish at finitely many $y$.

(You can also have some fun with a proof via ramification, but let me give the low-tech methods first.)

Answer (score -2):

I think yes, it is possible:

$f(x, y) = (x + y)^2 - 1.$

roots for y0 are:

$x = y_0 - 1,$

$x = y_0 + 1.$

Comment: I don't understand. If roots of $f(x,y_0) = 0$ are $y_0 -1$ and $y_0 + 1$, then they are not equal so it is not a multiple root